# Is there a way to fix QuickLook bugs

Tags: catalina, preview, big-sur, quicklook

I'm experiencing multiple bugs with QuickLook since Catalina. They are still present on Big Sur 11.1.

1°) Reversed slideshow

To reproduce:

- select multiple pictures
- press space bar
- the slideshow order is reversed: the last picture is displayed instead of the first, and we have to use the left arrow to display the next picture

It also happens in fullscreen.

2°) Alt key no longer zooms to 100%

Previously we could press the alt key to zoom at 100% (one pixel of the picture = one pixel of the monitor). It was perfect to see quickly know if a picture is sharp or not.

Now we have to press MAJ-CMD-0 to zoom, MAJ-CMD-9 to unzoom. And in Preview.app, it's not MAJ-CMD-9/0, but ALT-CMD-9/0. o_O

3°) Two-fingers double-tap to zoom does not go back

To reproduce:

- select a picture
- press space bar
- execute a two-fingers double-tap on the trackpad (or one-finger double-tap on a Magic Mouse) -> it zooms to 100% (or 200%, see #4 below)
- do it again. We'd expect it to unzoom, but it instead zooms to 200%, and we can't go back to see the entire picture with that gesture. The only way is to execute a pinch, which takes much more time to do.

4°) HiDPI monitors are not correctly supported

To reproduce:

- use a HiDPI monitor (say a 27" 4K monitor)
- select a photo (say a 1600px * 900px picture)
- press space bar
- the picture is displayed at twice its size (like if it was 3200px * 1800px), making it pixelated. When using the MAJ-CMD-9/0 shortcut to zoom/unzoom to 100%, it instead zooms to 200%, making the feature useless to know if it's sharp or not.

5°) Scrolling no longer works in fullscreen index sheet view

To reproduce:

- select many photos
- press alt-space to start QuickLook fullscreen
- open the index sheet
- try to scroll having your cursor above the background, it does not work. If your cursor is above a picture, it does.

The problem does not happen if we're not in fullscreen.

6°) There's a weird flickering when opening the index sheet view

To reproduce:

- select many photos
- press alt-space to start QuickLook fullscreen
- open the index sheet
- the animation is broken: the thumbnails first appear above the image that was displayed fullscreen, then that image comes back above the thumbnails and is animated, and finally the thumbnails are back.

Does someone managed to fix at least a few of them?

Thanks

EDIT: I submitted a bug report, please upvote if you want it to be fixed: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252189076?sortBy=best

Comment: did you find a solution to this problem? I have the same

Comment: No, I have submitted a report to Apple. Please do the same if you'd like to see it fixed ;)